# How to find exact draggable grid line position in rulerguides.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gridlines, rulers

I am currently working in [rulerguides.js](http://mark-rolich.github.io/RulersGuides.js/). And i customized into particular div for  rulers and grid line.REFER THIS [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/y7976fvw/5/). Rulers are working fine for me but drag-gable create div (**GRID LINES**) calculated from  body element only , that means top of window and left edges of window.Here In my code i can send particular div for rulers

```
var evt         = new Event(),
    dragdrop    = new Dragdrop(evt),
    rg          = new RulersGuides(evt, dragdrop,document.getElementById('workarea'));
```

I need to start from particular div
 (For example : **ruler h unselectable** class will create horizontal grid line and **ruler v unselectable** class will create vertical grid line in my working area.)
How to get draggable starting element ? And i need to start in particular div just like image 
[image: Demo Image].

I am struggle for more than 2 days.How to solve this issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually RulersGuides.js is not intended to be used in containers other than document body, so I would think about placing it in an iframe.
If you really need to have it a in a  div, here are some adjustments needed:

1. Update getWindowSize, getScrollPos and getScrollSize functions to calculate container dimensions.
2. Instead of using vBound and hBound in mousedown handler you need to introduce vLowBound, vHighBound, etc., where container's left and top offsets will be taken in account, like this:

   ```
   if (vLowBound === 0) {
       vLowBound = container.offsetLeft;
       vHighBound = vRuler.offsetWidth + vLowBound;
       hLowBound = container.offsetTop;
       hHighBound = hRuler.offsetHeight + hLowBound;
   }
   ```

with appropriate checks

```
if (
    (
        (x > vLowBound && x < vHighBound) ||
        (y > hLowBound && y < hHighBound)
    ) && rulerStatus === 1
)
```

and then

```
if (y > hLowBound && y < hHighBound) {
```

and

```
} else if (x > vLowBound && x < vHighBound) {
```

accordingly

3. Update removeInboundGuide accordingly in the same way.

Other than that, I think there'll be needed some changes in dom dimensions calculations, dialogs etc.

Please refer to the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrolich/r9bujj1q/8/) for the details.

Comment: HI @Mark Rolich.. Thank you for Your valuable answer.I am really happy about your answer.At the same time i would change pixel into inches in my given fiddle..did you seen it? is it correct manner to implement inches?or else any other idea for this?

Comment: Hi Vivek. Actually I think it's really difficult to map real world measurement units such as inches to pixels which can differ on different devices and screen sizes. There was a discussion about that on [github](https://github.com/mark-rolich/RulersGuides.js/issues/14#issuecomment-62690014)

Comment: Hi @MarkRolich..Your absolutely correct screen resolution will be differ one another.But I have 525 X 300 px it will shown 3.5x2 inches (include 150DPI) http://auctionrepair.com/pixels.html. How to get this calculation?